# Prove that if a function's average is nondecreasing then the function is nondecreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $\omega:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\omega(0) = 0$ and $\xi(s) = \frac{1}{s}\int\limits_{0}^s \omega(t)dt$ is nondecreasing, i.e., $\forall s,s': s\leq s'$, $\xi(s)\leq \xi(s')$. Show that $\omega(t)$ is nondecreasing a.e., i.e. find a function $w(t)$ such that $w$ is nondecreasing and $\omega = w$ a.e.

I was able to show the reverse implication easily, that if $\omega$ is nondecreasing then $\xi$ is nondecreasing. This way seems more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is false. Take $\omega(t)=5t$ on $[0,2]$, then $18-4t$ on $[2,3]$. The average increases from 0 to 5 over $[0,2]$. Now over $[2,3]$ the function $\omega(t)$ is decreasing but it remains $\ge6$, So the average continues to increase, and in fact reaches 6 at $t=3$.

We could now take $\omega(t)$ to be any increasing function for $t\ge3$, eg $\omega(t)=2t$. That will ensure that the average is increasing over the entire domain.