# $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt$ is monotone if and only if $f$ is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and $F:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt$. Prove that $f$ is monotone if and only if $F$ is monotone.
I could prove the "$\implies$" part by only using $f$'s continuity (I just made the substitution $t=xs$ and used $f$'s monotony).
For the "$\impliedby$" I don't really have many ideas. I tried to differentiae $F$, but to no avail. I also tried to start from the definition of monotony, but I couldn't relate $F$'s monotony to $f$'s.

Comment: Are you sure the "$\impliedby$" part is true? It looks implausible to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452904/prove-that-if-a-functions-average-is-nondecreasing-then-the-function-is-nondecr

Comment: It might be useful to think in terms of discrete averages for intuition.  If you have a set $S$ then the average of $S \cup \{x\}$ is bigger than $S$ if and only if $x$ is bigger than the average of $S$.  However, $x$ doesn't have to be bigger than *every* element of $S$, only bigger than the average.  Similarly for the continuous analog; for $F(x)$ to be increasing we need $f(x)$ to be more than the average of $f(t)$, $t \leq x$, but we don't need to insist $f(x)$ be the greatest value of $f(t)$, $t\leq x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us build a counterexample. We take obviously increasing function
$$
F(x) = x + \sin x
$$
and show that corresponding $f$ is not monotone. One should have
$$
\int_{0}^x f(t) dt = x^2 + x \sin x.
$$
Differentiate this equality and get
$$
f(x) = 2x + \sin x + x\cos x.
$$
It's not difficult to verify that this function is not monotone. Indeed, the derivative
$$
f'(x) = 2 + 2\cos x -x\sin x
$$
takes both positive and negative values.

Comment: Thank you, I also had my doubts about it!